# What is an uninhabited type?

Tags: type-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inhabitation

The wiki article above says,

> To be sound, such a system must have uninhabited types.

What is the definition an uninhabitated type? Do all programming languages have uninhabited types? What would be an example in Haskell? Or C? Or Java? Or Python?

Comment: I believe that `void` is an uninhabited type.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus 
What about void pointers or functions "returning" void ;-)

@Hank Consider dependent types, or type families in Haskell, such as the type of all m-by-n matrices. Then when m and n are negative integers, then the type of m-by-n matrices is uninhabited. In programming, `Fin n` is used to denote the type of the *first n-many non-negative integers*; then `Fin 0` is empty/uninhabited.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: no, `void` is just a misnomer for the unit type. If `void` were uninhabited, it would be impossible to write a function of type `int → void`.

Answer (score 3):

"Inhabited" is the properly constructive notion of "non-empty". The idea is that to demonstrate that a type is inhabited requires exhibiting a particular construction with that type, while 'non-empty' means merely demonstrating that it is impossible to demonstrate that there are no such constructions.

"Uninhabited" is the negation of this, and so is equivalent to being empty, even constructively.

Haskell does not have an uninhabited type. For instance `undefined` is a valid term of every type. C, Java and any language with general recursion is not going to qualify either, although C and Java have many other problems even being considered analogues of formal logic. Python doesn't even have types in the type theoretic sense (or it has a single type that classifies everything trivially).

The reason why `void` does not really qualify is that it is not a 'type with no values', but a type where you disallowed from naming/manipulating values, because those values would be trivial. It is analogous to the unit type, with one featureless value.

Answer (score 3):

A type $A$ is inhabited if there exists a term $t$ of type $A$.

In typed programming languages with recursion all types are inhabited. Given any type `A`, consider the term `f()` where `f : unit → A` just calls itself:

```
function A f() { return f(); }
```

(Sure, `f()` cycles, but it has type `A`)

Side comment: the type `void` in C/C++ is inhabited, we just never get to observe its values. Indeed, since it is possible to implement a terminating function `g : int → void`, it cannot be the case that `void` is empty.

So, if we want to think of types as logical statements and their elements as proofs, then there ought to be a type that corresponds to `False`, and this type better be empty (because we cannot prove `False`).

Comment: I feel like while your definition of uninhabited is technically correct, there is a valuable distinction to be drawn between types that can actually be constructed and types that cannot. For example, a sum type variant that contains a type that cannot be constructed at all, can be eliminated from consideration while memory layout is being determined.

Comment: What is your point?

Comment: My point is that "In typed programming languages with recursion all types are inhabited" is not a very useful practical definition. In typed programming languages with recursion, there is a useful distinction between types which can have an actual value be constructed for them, and types which cannot. I don't know if there's a more specific term for it, but as a practitioner I call the latter "uninhabited" and everyone around me understands what I mean.

Comment: Yes, there is a more specific way of saying what you are trying to say. One way to give operational semantics is to define a notion of *value*, which differs from expression, and to set up semantics so that closed expressions evaluate to values. In such languages there can be types that have no values, for instance if they allow empty sum types. ...

Comment: ... However, this distinction depends on having a suitable notion of value, as well as on evaluation strategy – it is hardly an appropriate thing to mention when the OP is struggling with basics. It is better for the *first* to see how recursion is used to inhabit any type, and not to drag in nuances of operational semantics,

Comment: Thanks for the more specific terminology!

I understand your viewpoint now, thanks. Though I personally would say that the approach of first understanding what makes empty sum types special, and then asking the question "oh but what about bottom" matches my brain better.

Comment: "Bottom" is a semantic notion, so that's yet another way of approaching the question. We interpret types as [domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory), and depending how things are set up, every type migth contain $\bot$. Once again, we could make a distinction between values and computations. Values get interpreted by *pre-domains*, which need not have bottoms, and computations by domains, which have bottoms. This nicely distinguishes the difference between "innert" values  (cannot be bottom, it's already computed) and computations, which require further evaluation, and can cycle.

Answer (score 2):

An uninhabited type is a type which **cannot have a representation at runtime** no matter what you do, and enforces this is **in a structural manner**.

I'm going to use Rust as an example, because it does have uninhabited types. Rust has enums, for example:

```rust
enum Color {
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Rgb(u8, u8, u8),
}
```

And you can specify a color, e.g. `Color::Red` or `Color::Rgb(255, 255, 255)`.

But what if you declare an empty enum:

```rust
enum Never {}
```

How would you construct a value of this enum? What goes after `Never::`?

The answer is "it cannot be done". There is no possible representation of `Never` in the language. This makes the type uninhabited.

---

What does "in a structural manner" mean? Another way to put it is "even disregarding encapsulation boundaries". A lot of code is written to uphold certain invariants outside of an encapsulation boundary.

For example, consider a file where the only contents are:

```rust
pub struct MyType(());
```

This type has no attached constructors, and the module doesn't have any functions that return `MyType`. In other words, `MyType` can be named as a type but cannot be constructed.

However, `MyType` can be *represented* at runtime, just not *created* at runtime. In other words, the lack of constructability of `MyType` is enforced via *encapsulation boundaries* rather than it being a property of the structure of `MyType` itself. This means that `MyType` **is not** uninhabited. But it might be the best you can do in many languages.

---

This is related to why enums are called "sum types" and structs are called "product types" -- the identity element of the sum operation is zero, and the identity element of the product operation is one.